# siunitx package not executing uncertainty properly

Tags: siunitx

I must begin by saying that I have read the manual. But maybe I've done a crap job of it.

I have three problems:

1. I want the values in the uncertainty values brackets to express as plus/minus. Instead, they only come as brackets.
2. I want the range units to NOT repeat. I am unable to do this despite specifying it in the preamble.
3. I want to add decimals in the uncertainty, but it gives me errors.

(Additional request) Can we convert all zeros in the document to a with a backslash across it or a dot at the center?

The minimal code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[alsoload=synchem,%
            range-phrase=--,%
            repeatunits=false%
            ]{siunitx}  

\begin{document}
The temperature measured was \SI{14(1)}{\kelvin} and was observed between time points \SIrange{34}{90}{\second}.

\SI{1.45(2)e-4}{\Molar}
%\SI{1.45(0.2)e-4}(\Molar} throws an error: "Invalid certainty in numerical input".
\end{document}
```

This is my output:

[image: This is my output].

My OS is Linux Mint.
My front end is TeXMaker 5.0.3
I use pdflatex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20.

Comment: Wow! You've got v1 options there - I'm currently finalising v3 and thought 'I'll not need to worry at all about v1'. Now you've worried me :)

Comment: Uh Oh! What's v1 here? Which version is too old?

Comment: The options you show are from the first release series of `siunitx`, which was replaced in 2010 by the second one. I'm very doubtful you are using the first release: more likely you are using v2 with the back-compatibility options enabled. I'll cover both in an answer.

Comment: Thanks. Also, can I say how flattered I am to actually be typing to the one that wrote the package. It's been an indispensable package for my thesis. 
An overall thank you for such a kickass package!

Comment: I'm not sure why `repeatunits = false` is not working for you: it does for me. Could you add `\listfiles` to your input and report the version line for `siunitx` from the `File list` you get in the log?

Comment: Under FileList:
 siunitx.sty    2020/01/15 v2.7u A comprehensive (SI) units package

siunitx-version-1.cfg    2017/11/26 v2.7k siunitx: Version 1 settings

siunitx-abbreviations.cfg    2017/11/26 v2.7k siunitx: Abbreviated units

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the load options you give are from version 1.x, which was replaced in 2010 by version 2. As such, I think you are likely using version 2 but loading it with older options.

The requests are separate, so I will take them one at a time.

1. You can tell `siunitx` to print uncertainties separately using `\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}` (in v1 `\sisetup{seperr}`)
2. You can suppress repeat of range units using `\sisetup{range-units = single}` (v1 `sisetup{repeatunits = false}`). Looking at the code, it seems the v1 emulation has an bug here as it doesn't cover ranges: I'll adjust.
3. The uncertainty given in 'short' form is expressed based on the last digits of the main number. So you would need `\SI{1.450(2)e4}{\Molar}` to get an extra place. You could use the format `\SI{1.45 \pm 0.002e4}{\Molar}`, which will correctly add the places.